# excel: получить максимальное значение по условию (+ проблема с МАКСЕСЛИ)

Tags: функции, excel, max

есть 2 столбца - в первом записана дата, во втором значение

требуется найти максимальное значение среди данных соответствующих 2021 году

использую Excel 2016

Сделал так:

```
=МАКСЕСЛИ($B1:$B100000;$A1:$A100000;"ГОД($A1)=2021")
```

не сработало, получаю `#ИМЯ?`

но самое странное, почему то в Excel 2016 у меня вообще отсутствует такая функция, хотя в помощи заявлено, что данная функция появилась как раз в Excel 2016!

Посему такие вопросы:

1. почему функция отсутствует и как ее подключить
2. как реализовать требуемый функционал без `МАКСЕСЛИ`
3. в самом моем решении где ошибка? подозреваю, что условие `"ГОД($A1)=2021"` все таки в таком виде использовать нельзя

Comment: "ГОД($A1)=2021" - в этом фрагменте нет ссылки - это все текст (Вы взяли в кавычки все!)

Comment: а с чем может быть проблема, что такая функция не обнаруживается?

Comment: Проверьте, как записана функция, нет ли в имени латиницы. Исправьте условие: `...;ГОД($A1:$A100000);2021)` Справка по функции нормально описана: https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883

Answer (score 1):

по поводу вопроса №2 решил следующим образом:

```
{=МАКС(ЕСЛИ(ГОД($A1:$A100000) = 2021; $B1:$B100000))}
```

правда не очень понимаю пока почему при Ctrl-Shift-Enter данная формула срабатывает в таком виде, но при попытке что-то в ней отредактировать, эти `{}` слетают и надо заново использовать Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Comment: Все верно. Ввод формулы массива - `Ctrl-Shift-Enter`, при этом формула заключается в фигурные скобки. При редактировании формулы скобки удаляются, ведь Excel не знает, что у Вас на уме. Может, Вы хотите сделать обычную формулу, не "массивную". Примите это, как должное :)